# A Specified Percentage Of Quorum Is Required To Carry A Motion

Tags: parliamentary-procedure

The Bylaws state that a quorum is 25% of active members (130 x .25 = 33). A specific vote requires 75% of the quorum in order to pass (33 x .75 = 25). My question is, if 100 people are in attendance, and the quorum threshold is only 33, does the 75% of the quorum (25) vote requirement cause the vote to be affirmed even though 75 people might vote against the item?

Comment: Does this group specify *Roberts Rules of Order* as its parliamentary manual, or some other manual, or make no specification?

Comment: Do the bylaws say "yes vote of 75% of the quorum is required for a motion to pass", or does it say "75% of the (valid) votes cast must be affirmative for a motion to pass". If the former, then yes (strange but not inconceivable). You should give us the verbatim text.

Comment: Here are the excerpts from the Bylaws for defining the quorum and "75% of quorum" stipulation.

Comment: Roberts Rules is the parliamentary manual.    Here are the excerpts from the Bylaws for defining the quorum and "75% of quorum" stipulation. "QUORUMS - A quorum shall consist of 25% of the persons who meet the requirements of active membership. Members who are homebound, hospitalized, or in care facilities shall not count against the quorum requirement."                                                                                        "An affirmative vote of 75% of the Church Membership quorum is required to call the proposed candidate as Senior Pastor.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what manual of parlimentary procedure is used by the group if any (see comment). But in general i would take the 25 vote requirement to be a floor, but that a majority of those voting, however many they are, must vote in favor for a measure to pass. If that majority is less than 25 votes, it still doesn't pass due to this 75% of a quorum requirement.

Answer (score 1):

### No

Presumably, the 75% of the quorum requirement is an *additional* requirement for the particular motion over and above the requirement that all motions must be carried by a simple majority of members present and able to vote. So it needs to pass both thresholds.

For your example, 33-50 members present, the threshold is 25 - the 75% of the quorum requirement. For 51+ members present the threshold is 50% of the members present rounded up - the simple majority requirement.

This is an unusual provision and it is likely that the drafters meant 75% of members present and eligible to vote which is much more typical. However, it is unambiguous and workable as written.